# z-index issue in firefox 5, chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, z-index

I am in the process of doing css fixes for IE6 and 7 and I ran across some z-index issues. No big deal, I just went through them one at a time. Well in trying to fix them, I've uncovered a bigger z-index issue in firefox and chrome. I have a link in the header that when clicked triggers a dropdown to slide down. The problem is that it drops down behind the navigation area just below the header.

Here is the css for the dropdown and the nav:

```
#topNav{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}

#minicart{
    position:relative;
    width:355px;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:#fff;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #666;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #666;
    behavior:url(http://192.168.1.104/magento/skin/frontend/asi/default/assets/PIE.htc);
    color:#000; 
    z-index:9999;
}
```

So you can see that `#minicart` z-index is way higher than `#topNav`. What I can't figure out is why `#topNav` is on top even though the z-index is smaller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We don't "fix" Firefox and Chrome to make things work in IE. We fix IE, period. You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear. If it works in IE, but not the other far more modern browsers, your code is wrong. Fix your code. In addition, IE has a number of issues with z-index you can find by Googling.

Comment: @Max unfortunately no, it's still in internal testing

Comment: @Rob I guess the bigger question I have here is not about IE and its many issues or trying to fix something in chrome/firefox, I'm well aware of these things. The question is what would make and element with a higher z-index be displayed behind an element with a lower z-index

Answer (score 0):

At first, remove one of the two `z-index` you have at the same element.

Then make some troubleshooting in the hard work way. Take away (comment out) all code lines and leave only the `z-index` along with some way of making them visual, like `background-color`.

If this works, add one line at a time and test it.

If it *doesn't* work, there is something else wrong on your page.

Comment: that's what I have been doing, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, your `#minicart` has an ancestor that forms a new stacking context (e.g. has a non-auto z-index or has a CSS transform applied or has opacity not equal to 1) and is z-ordered below the `#topNav`.  It's hard to say more than that without seeing the actual page.